# List content of Folder and mark their type (folder or file)

Tags: java, file, repository, explorer

Okay I think this is a really stupid question with a really easy answer but I am stuck at the moment :/

I am rendering the content of a repository in a JTree. But loading the whole content each time is unnecessary. So what I want to do is somethink **like** a JTree (to view and handle folders in another way then the documents) but only load the content of the current folder. And on a double click on a folder, the content of this folder should be loaded and shown.

In one sentence: something like a file browser/windows explorer but only for a repository.

So should I still use JTree (where I dont know how to view a folder as none-leaf without childs so it is shown in another way) or a JList or something else?

EDIT: will not work

```
if (o.getType().getBaseTypeId().toString().equals("CMIS_FOLDER")) {     //if item is folder
                DefaultMutableTreeNode f = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(o.getName());
                f.setAllowsChildren(true);
                dmtn.add(f);
            } else
                dmtn.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(o.getName()));
```

Comment: Basically, you're after a lazy loading `JTree`, have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075463/expand-collapse-expand-issue-with-jtree-lazy-loading/15075909#15075909) for examples

Comment: Okay but if I have the list of the content of, for example, the root directory JTree doesnt know the difference between the folders and documents as I only return a MutableTreeNod (basically only leafes without children). Or is there also a solution for this?

Comment: When loading your `File`s, you can determine the type using `File#isDirectory`, you can then use the `setAllowsChildren` method of the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` class to mark it as a "folder"

Comment: Hmm not working ... see edit