# Java's Swing JTree treeWillExpand event timing - Does not update an swing element before expanding

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I recently entered java world and started a personal project but, as a newbie in Java, I have encountered a problem in Java's Swing JTree Component.

My issues occurs in a large code project (https://github.com/adrian-tilita/jTreeHelper) in the "LoadingObserver" so, to sum it up, I tried to replicate the issues in a rudimentary chunk of code (no package) in 3 files:

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        View.main(args);
    }
}
```

**EventHandler**

```
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeWillExpandListener;
import javax.swing.tree.ExpandVetoException;

public class EventHandler implements TreeWillExpandListener, TreeExpansionListener {
    private javax.swing.JLabel label;
    public void setLabel(javax.swing.JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException {
        this.label.setText("Loading...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
        this.label.setText("Loaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException {}

    @Override
    public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {}
}
```

**View**

```
public class View extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public View() {
        initComponents();
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
        handler.setLabel(jLabel1);
        this.jTree1.addTreeWillExpandListener(handler);
        this.jTree1.addTreeExpansionListener(handler);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTree1 = new javax.swing.JTree();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTree1);
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 233, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 365, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new View().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree1;
}
```

The view is just a generated netbeans form, with a few lines the constructor.

The issues I have is regarding the "treeWillExpand" event when I try to update a swing component (to loading), but, in my case, I only get the "loaded" text.

Am I doing something wrong or the event is not quite the event I am looking for?

Mainly, my question is: How do I update a Swing component on "TreeWillExpand" event?

PS: Be gentle, it is my first encounter with java.

Comment: First bad idea - `Thread.sleep(1000);`.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) why. See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: ok. for concurrency I do not quite agree or understand the full implications because invoking it in a single thread causes the same result so as I guess my problem is not a thread line  (I maybe stubborn on the thread issues but from test I've done this is not quite a thread issues). For the SwingWorker, I started documenting on how and what it does... and I hope is a solution for me ..

Comment: Swing is single threaded, `treeWillExpand` is called within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, meaning that when you call `Thread.sleep` within in, nothing is getting updated or painted (and no new events are been processed, essentially your program has hung). It's also possible that the time between setting `Loading` and `Loaded` is small enough for the API to optimise the updates so only `Loaded` is painted, but based on your example code, your problem is related to blocking the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075463/expand-collapse-expand-issue-with-jtree-lazy-loading) of a lazy loading tree ;)

Comment: Also, you might find that `treeDidExpand` is called immediately after `treeWillExpand`, withing the same event dispatching cycle, meaning that the painting is optimised to the last update.  If you need to block the execution of the code for some reason within `treeWillExpand`, then you might need to use something like [the Foxtrot API](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/docs/introduction.php), which will allow you to safely stop the execution of your code, but without it actually blocking the EDT (much like a modal dialog)

Comment: The exact issues off "lazy loading" is what I try to mimic. Using Thread.sleep just mimics a time-consuming process. My issue is that when the event is triggered I update a swing component then I process my data.. but, for reasons I quite don't understand yet, swing is waiting for the entire event to be completed before updating it's components.... it's like it has locked his updates before firing the events...

Comment: *"Using Thread.sleep just mimics a time-consuming process"* - Which is BLOCKING the Event Dispatching Thread, which is preventing it from updating the UI.  Until `treeWillExpand` returns, any new "paint" events WON'T be processed by the EDT. *"swing is waiting for the entire event to be completed before updating it's components"* - YES, Swing is SINGLE THREADED, calling `setText` does nothing more then raise a new "paint" event which is placed onto the end of the Event Queue to be processed later, after the current event dispatching cycle is complete.  This is how most GUI frameworks work